# VBA Excel Issue

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to write a code on excel 2003 to change the background colour of a cell based on the information I have manually entered in a previous cell. This is to show the customer satisfaction scores of our top 10 customers.

I have written this code below but I only know how to make it work for one cell and not for a range of cells. I am an amateur when it comes to using this so any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("B1").Value < Range("A1").Value Then Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Value Then Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
If Range("B1").Value > Range("A1").Value Then Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 45
If Range("B1").Value = 1 Then Range("B1").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

This code works perfectly for the one cell but I need to do this for a range of cells in different areas of the spreadsheet

I would like the code to work for cell F26 down to F35 to change colour on the basis of the information that is in column C26 down to C35. As this is over 12 months I would like the code to change the colours of the cells I26 down to I35 from the information in F26 down to F35 and so on.

Apologies if this sounds like an extremely stupid question but I am an amateur and just looking for some help from someone who is clued up on this

Comment: Can you post an example of what is contained in C26 to C35, F26 to F35 and I26 to I35? Hint: Instead of using code, you could use conditional formatting to achieve this.

Comment: C26-C35 has varying percentage figures. C26=56% C27=76% C28=83% and so on. The only numbers that will be input into F26 will be between 0% and 100%. I want the sheet to change the cell colour to red if F26 is less than 56% go yellow if its the same as 56% go orange if its an increase and turn green if its 100%. i have tried the conditional formatting but as this only has 3 conditions i am stuck

Comment: Take a look at @Kim's solution. I am sure, the code does what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

OK, then here is the detailed solution:

Column 3 should be hidden, this is just using the sign() formula function: =SIGN(B2-A2)
Note that the default background color of the column is the color you want to see for cases where sign=1

[image: this is how the sheet should look like]

And these are your conditional formatting rules. I did it for cell B2 only, then filled the formatting for the rest of the column. One rule for sign=1, one for sign=-1 and one for where B2 = 1.

[image: and these are your 3 rules]

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to do it in the `Worksheet_Change` event? This is going to slow down things a bit.

Anyway, there is no way to write the code like this for a range, you have to iterate through the cells in the range one by one. For example like this:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
For Each r In ws.Range("F26:F35")
    If r.Value < ws.Cells(r.Row, 3) Then r.Interior.ColorIndex = 3  '3 -- Column C
    '...
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a hidden column with a calculated value (sign of difference, for example) and use a conditional formatting set for that column because Martin is Right, this will slow down your Excel.

However if you really want to do that on that event handler, that routine receives a parameter that is the range that was modified. You can iterate through its rows or columns.

Comment: OP needs four different colors, if I am not mistaken, in Excel 2003 you can have only three rules in conditional formatting. (I haven't seen Excel 2003 for some time.)

Comment: Yeah, you're right with Excel 2003 but conditions 1, 2 and 3 can not be true at the same time so a default background and 3 conditionals are fairly enough, AFAIC.

Comment: i tried the conditional formatting but as its excel 2003 I am limited to 3 conditions. I appreciate I am behind the times using 2003 but its work related and not personal so I have no say on what excel we use. I think I may be best of using the 3 conditional formats and then just deleting them once I get 100% and manually change it. Probably be more hassle than writing all these codes

Comment: But 3 conditional formats are enough if you have one default color for your default status plus 3 conditions ... if you know what I mean.

Comment: I understand what you mean but putting it into practice is slightly different for me as I really am an amateur. I didnt realise all the work involved (to me it seems a lot of work but writing the codes are probably second nature to the majority of people who are on here). I wouldnt know how to do what you have advised in all honesty

Comment: OK, see my other answer please.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim oCell           As Range

For Each oCell In Target
    Call Input_Ranges(oCell, Range("F26:F35"), -3)
    Call Input_Ranges(oCell, Range("I26:I35"), -3)
    Call Input_Ranges(oCell, Range("L26:L35"), -3)
    Call Input_Ranges(oCell, Range("O26:O35"), -13)
Next oCell

End Sub

Public Sub Input_Ranges(oCell As Range, oRange As Range, iOffset As Integer)

    If Not Intersect(oCell, oRange) Is Nothing Then
        If oCell < oCell.Offset(0, iOffset) Then
             oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
         ElseIf oCell > oCell.Offset(0, iOffset) Then
             oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
         ElseIf oCell = oCell.Offset(0, iOffset) Then
             oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
         ElseIf oCell = 1 Then
             oCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
         End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I have modified the code a second time based on your request (comments).

Small explanation:
The Target is the range that is being changed and triggers the event.
The Intersect method checks if the Target lies within the range defined.
Offset checks the third column left from the Target range that has changed.
You can change this to any column you like.

Comment: This seems to be working fine however when I enter the information the cells still remain orange for 100% rather than change green. Sorry for all the questions

Comment: @Kim: You might want to move the For loop inside the If statement?

Comment: I'm sorry you guys, I left a mistake which I have rectified now. I wanted to check each cell to cover the different scenarios (change cell or entire range at once); now it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi Kim. I have changed the code as written above yet the 100% still remains orange rather than change to green.

Comment: Hey, I tested this too, and for me it works. Check carefully the values using debug.print or the locals window, and check the ranges carefully too using F8... Are the values correctly matched against each other? I edited the code to give =1 precedence to the other conditions.

Comment: If you doubt, use regular values instead of percentages to do the test. In debug mode, you will definitely be able to localize the problem.

Comment: Hi Kim. This is working now so I would like to thank you for your help. The only problem I have now is to replicate this, so that it runs on various ranges of cells. So I would Like I26:I35 to change colour based on the information in cells F26:F35, then for L26:L35 to read from I26:I35, then O26:O35 to change from L26:L35, C42:C51 to read from O26:O35. I appreciate I am pretty much asking you to do everything but I really am an amateur. Feel free to tell me to Shut up if I am asking too much

Comment: Hi Kim. Thank you for your patience and help. I tried the above and again the 100% remained orange. I have been given this as a way forward and not sure what you think

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim x As Integer
If Intersect(Target, Range("C4:C13")) Is Nothing Then
If Intersect(Target, Range("F4:F13")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End If
x = 3
Do
x = x + 1
If Range("F" & x).Value < Range("C" & x).Value Then Range("F" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
If Range("F" & x).Value = Range("C" & x).Value Then Range("F" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
If Range("F" & x).Value > Range("C" & x).Value Then Range("F" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
If Range("F" & x).Value = 1 Then Range("F" & x).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Loop Until x = 13
End Sub

Comment: Well, I can't understand really what could be wrong because I tested and copy-pasted my code directly from the module on to SO. Are you sure you properly tested and provided the correct parameters to the sub (use F8 and check all values carefully)? I haven't got anything against your code if it works, but what I tried to provide you was an easy way to add as many ranges as you like to make it more dynamic (by simply providing range + offset as arguments).

Comment: I'm not trying to say there is anything wrong with it, its probably something I have done wrong in all honesty and just struggling to work out what I have done. I was just showing my code as an example and I appreciate all your effort as it has gone a long way to helping me understand all this. Sorry for all the hassle and I hopefully will get my head around it eventually